# no GetAngles() member in JointState Class in Gazeo Api 9?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

error:

```
 /home/robot/rtt_gazebo/rtt_gazebo_examples/src/default_gazebo_component.cpp:107:41: error: ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<gazebo::physics::JointState> >::value_type {aka class gazebo::physics::JointState}’ has no member named ‘GetAngles’
         state_pos_[j] = joint_states[j].GetAngles();
```

code:

```
 joint_states[j](JointPtr gazebo_joints_[j]);
        state_pos_[j] = joint_states[j].GetAngles();
  std::vector<gazebo::physics::JointPtr> gazebo_joints_;
  std::vector<gazebo::physics::JointState> joint_states;
```

i'm using gazebo9 version. as i studied [this](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/7.1.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1JointState.html) gazebo 9 api jointstate class, their is presence of getangle member in class jointstate, than why is this error coming.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18554/no-getangles()-member-in-jointstate-class-in-gazeo-api-9?/) by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 56 on 2018-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The documentation you linked to is for Gazebo 7.1.0, you should look [here](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/9.0.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1JointState.html) for the Gazebo 9.0.0 documentation (note the version on the URL).

If you check the [Migration guide](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/gazebo9/Migration.md), you'll see that the `GetAngles` changed to `Positions`:

```
Deprecation: const std::vector<math::Angle> GetAngles() const
Replacement: const std::vector<double> &Positions() const
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Roberto Z.](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8359/roberto-z./) on 2022-05-11**:
The link is broken. Found this one instead: https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo11/Migration.md